# Adicionar um sidemenu no template Blank do ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic, mobile

Olá!

Eu criei o meu projeto utilizando o template blank do ionic1, porem surgiu a necessidade de adicionar um sidemenu no meu projeto. Não consegui de forma alguma adicionar esse menu e gostaria de saber se alguém já fez isso e se poderia compartilhar conosco como foi feito. Como já tenho boa parte dele pronto fica bastante chato ter que criar um novo projeto com sidemenu e ir migrando. Agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, ja fiz um app com side menu e é bem simples.

Da uma olhada na documentação sobre ele nesse [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/)

Você só precisa usar as diretivas do próprio Ionic, de uma olhada.

Nesse exemplo abaixo eu peguei de um projeto meu, basicamente você tem:

- Container de menus do Ionic: `ion-side-menus`
- Conteúdo do container: `ion-side-menu-content`
- Barra de navegação, a barra superior do app: `ion-nav-bar`

  - Botão voltar "nativo", responde ao histórico de navegação: `ion-nav-back-button`
  - Um container de botões a serem inseridos na barra superior: `ion-nav-buttons`
- Componente de navegação das views do app que eu quero que apareçam dentro do container do menu
- Ai fora do container de conteúdo, vem os menus e seus conteúdos: `ion-side-menu`

---

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="appView"></ion-nav-view> // nav view para trocar as telas mantendo o contexto do menu
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="page2">
                    Página 1
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="page2">
                    Página 2
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```